# Apscheduler with django on windows server

Tags: python, django, iis, windows-server-2012, apscheduler

I'm using django for my website. In that, I need to run a job automatically. This django app is hosted on the IIS Windows server.

When I run the app locally (by command prompt), it works. But in the IIS, the job is not running.

Below here, I put some codes and its location. My project name is `myProject` and my app name is `myApp`

In myApp/init.py:

```
import os

if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) != 'true':
    default_app_config = 'myApp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

In myApp/apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myApp'
    def ready(self):
        from taskscheduler import updater
        updater.start()
```

In myApp/views.py:

```
def job():
   #some codes
   #and a row creation whether the app runs successfully or failed
```

In updater/updater.py:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

from myApp import views

def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(views.job, trigger='cron',hour='*', minute='20')
    scheduler.start()

import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Please help me sortout.
Thanks in advance